# fiber cable connectivity

Tags: storage, fiber, brocade

For switch to server connectivity with fiber cable:

1. TX end connected of server  will be connected to the TX of the switch  and
   vice versa.
2. To validate the TX end, see through the cable. The one with light is TX
   end.

Please confirm my understanding. Also suggest if i need to check anything
else.

Regards
ajain

Answer (score 3):

You should never (ever) look into a fiber cable with equipment (lasers) attached to it. You can severely damage your retina. Use a flashlight in one end to check if you have the pairs correct.

TX on one side goes into RX on the other side and vice versa.

Comment: Do not stare into laser with remaining eye.

Comment: what if i need to connect two brocade switches. In that scenario also TX should go to RX and vice versa? Fiber optics doesnt works like Ethernet ? In ether net we connect switch by Straight cable to server.

Comment: Fiber optics have one pair of "cables", one for each direction of light. Yes, the same rules apply. TX in one port is connected to RX at the other side.